# What does the `--space` parameter mean in Confluence SOAP interface?

Tags: soap, command-line, confluence

I am using `atlassian-cli-3.8.0`, and attempting to run the following command after successfully running `confluence --action getServerInfo`.

```
confluence --action getPage --title Foo
```

However, this command fails with the following error message.

```
This function requires a non-blank value for parameter: space
```

In the documentation [here](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CSOAP/Documentation#Documentation-space), the only description for the option `--space` is `Space Key`. That is completely meaningless to me, but I hope that someone who has already struggled with confluence might know better.

**What option is supposed to be passed to `--space`, and what does it mean?**

Answer (score 1):

This was incredibly hard to Google for, because the poor choice of names in this parameter.

The `Space Key` is referring to the unique identifier for what amounts to a directory in the Confluence Wiki. It is generally the word in the URL between the two `/`, and is documented [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Working+with+Spaces).